# QGIS 3.14 python environment path details

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis-3

I can use the following python statements/commands to get information about the version of Python that QGIS 3.14 supports. I use these in QGIS built-in python console

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())

import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.version_info)
```

Is there a one-line command that will print the full path of the associated python interpreter to the python console?

Answer (score 2):

Not really specific to QGIS, only Python stuff. Run the following to get what you want

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. From the python console in QGIS this returns `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.14\bin\qgis-bin.exe` which is still useful information. In the meantime I found `print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])` which is a bit closer for my purposes as it returns the directory in which the python exe is located. However it places `~` in the output for some reason and seems to truncate some parts of the fullpath name

Comment: @TrevP is it something like 'C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\' ? because that's normal these are old alias used for backwards compatibility.
https://superuser.com/questions/529400/how-does-progra1-path-notation-work

Comment: @ Louis Cottereau Yes exactly that!. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

When using QGIS 3.20.3 on Ubuntu, [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) is the executable binary for the Python interpreter. According to the [official Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable):

> A `string` giving the absolute path of the executable binary for the Python interpreter, on systems where this makes sense. If Python is unable to retrieve the real path to its executable, `sys.executable` will be an empty `string` or `None`.

Working with QGIS 3.20.3 on Windows 10, `sys.executable` is the QGIS executable which is wrong. I opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/45646

---

As a workaround on Windows, you could search for the executable in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

The example below works for me in the QGIS Python console on Windows and Ubuntu.

```py
import os
import sys

def find_python():

    if sys.platform != "win32":
        return sys.executable

    for path in sys.path:
        assumed_path = os.path.join(path, "python.exe")
        if os.path.isfile(assumed_path):
            return assumed_path

    return None

print(find_python())
```

**Note:** Not tested with virtual environments.